# Correct way to submit a mail form using ajax? - no JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I'm trying to handle a php mailform with ajax. It's a simple form that sends a message to my e-mail with the users phonenumber etc.

I'm not experienced with php at all but I got it to send me mail using a regular submit and then returning to the index page.

As this does not provide any feedback to the user this isn't working for me. I've found some examples using JQuery. I've also seen people using both GET and POST. I'm confused now how I should proceed.

The JQuery version of what I'm trying to achieve would look similar to this I guess.

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "mail.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#myForm').html("<div id='response'></div>");
    $('#response').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>");
  }
});

<?php
$mail = $_POST['email '];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = 'new submit';
$text = $_POST['message'];
$to = “yourmail@domain.com”;
$message =” You received  a mail from “.$mail;
$message .=” Text of the message : “.$text;
mail($to, $subject,$message)
?>
```

Comment: Just curious, why not use jQuery?

Comment: @ cereallarceny I don't think it's justified to use a library for 1 submit function...

Comment: !?!... All you want to do is modify the page's DOM on success, right?  I'm having trouble seeing where your problem is.

Comment: BTW, I -1'd your comment, then reversed, only because I don't like to be down on Stackoverflow newbies.  Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow.com!   However, do I think you could phrase your question better.  I fail to see how this question is useful to anybody.

Comment: Correct, but I would argue that using a Google CDN hosted version of jQuery (which is likely cached in everyone's browsers already) would not be much additional load time.  And I'd also bet that this won't be the last time you'll use jQuery on your website.

Comment: @JayC: I think you're mistaken, I wasn't being condescending in the slightest.  It was an honest question.

Comment: I understand it is an honest question, and I detected no condescension.  But the only way I can figure to answer your question is to answer the question "How does AJAX work?" and/or "How do I modify a web page using javascript?", and there are plenty of tutorials out there for that.  Look, if you need help with that, lets start at MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX,

Comment: Well, I'd use something like this:

var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML= 'Thanks for submit';
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'mail.php' + '?' + datastring,true);
xmlhttp.send();

My question is if this would be the right way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
<form id="form" method="post" name="mailform" action="mail.php" onsubmit="mail(); return false;">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Stuff</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="stuff">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<p id="result" style="display: none">
<img src="images/succes.png"><br>
Thank you
</p>

/*----------------------------*/

function mail() {
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var name = form.name.value; 
var email = form.email.value; 
var phone = form.phone.value; 
var message = form.message.value; 
var valid = true;

if (!name) {form.name.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9481'; valid = false; }
else {form.name.style.backgroundColor = '';}
if (!email && !phone) {form.email.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9481'; form.phone.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9481'; valid = false;}
else {form.email.style.backgroundColor = ''; form.phone.style.backgroundColor = '';}
if (!message) {form.message.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9481'; valid = false;}
else {form.message.style.backgroundColor = '';}
if (email) {
    var patt=/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/gi;
    var result=patt.test(email);
    if (!result) {form.email.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9481'; valid = false;}
    else form.email.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
if (phone) {
    var patt=/[^0-9|\-| ]/g;
    var result=patt.test(phone);
    if (result) {form.phone.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9481'; valid = false;}
    else form.phone.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
if (!valid) return false;

var datastr = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "ok") {
            form.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("result").style.display = '';
            }
            else {
            form.message.value= "That doesn't seem right";
            }       
        }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","mail.php?" + datastr,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

/*----------------------------*/

<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$etc...

if(IsInjected($name)||IsInjected($visitor_email)||IsInjected($phone)||IsInjected($message)) 
{
    echo "Something fishy going on?";
    exit;
}

[...]
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo "ok";

function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, jQuery is better than the natural way of using AJAX. But for the answer, firstly you should create a XmlHttp object in JavaScript. Then you can send your value to your page with the proper GET or POST method. After that, you can track the process by getting the state of posted request which it's implemented in stateChanged function. That's All!

```
var xmlhttp

function retrive(url, str){
    xmlhttp = GetXMLHTTPObject();
    if(xmlhttp==null){
        alert("Your browser doesn't support the ajax.");
        return;
    }
    var script=url;
    script=script+"?value="+str;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",script,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
}

function stateChanged(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 0){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "not initialized";
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "has been set up";
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "has been sent";
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 3){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "in process";
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

function GetXMLHTTPObject(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        //code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think it's better to see the definition of XmlHttpObject.